# Render an item trough displaysuite?

Tags: 6, theming, display-suite

Admitted, I don't truly understand [Displaysuite](https://drupal.org/node/644662).

What I need, is, something of the following:

```
foreach (get_certain_nodes(), $nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $rendered_node = call_displaysuite_to_render_the_node($node, 'build_mode_foo');
  $output .= $rendered_node;
}
```

The missing link is how to render the node, using a predefined build mode. Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering a Display Suite build mode is quite easy. If you know how. ;-)

```
foreach (get_certain_nodes(), $nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $node->build_mode = 'my_build_mode'; // Enter the name of your build mode here
  $rendered_node = node_view($node);
  $output .= $rendered_node;
}
```

By adding a 'build_mode' variable to the node object Display Suite will recognize it as something it has to render in `node_view()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but maybe it helps to have a look at the [nd_views_node_helper](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--nd--nd.module/function/nd_views_node_helper/6) function. If I understand correctly, it's the helper function that allows Views rows to be rendered through Display Suite.

You can also make your custom code dependent on views: create a view which takes node IDs as argument and renders the nodes through Display Suite.

Hope that helps!

Comment: One of the "problems" is that we cannot use views here (yay!). But I feared that something this trivial would become a Gigantic Project using DS. Looking at the views-implementation of DS helps a lot though. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck! I'd like to see your final solution once you found it.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [API page for D7 node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7) the second argument is the view_mode which could be a display suite view mode if you like.

```
foreach (get_certain_nodes(), $nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $rendered_node = node_view($node, 'build_mode_foo');
  $output .= drupal_render($rendered_node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the display "Full node" for a given content type. Go to /admin/structure/ds/layout and choose the Content Type you need to edit. In the section "Custom display settings" activate the view mode "Full content" and hit save. Now you can edit the "Full content" display to whatever you want to do with it ...

Comment: There seems to be some misunderstanding here. I have a module (custom) which pulls a list of nodes from the database. All I want, is to render that list trough DS, rather then simply theme("node", ...);